# TFS 2012 - How to make members of different teams have different current iterations?

Tags: tfs, alm

We have implemented TFS 2012 successfully and have been using it well for a while now.
Now we have a situation where 2 teams work on the same tfs project but with different iterations.

Though it is easy to achieve it, one thing I could not solve: is it possible to have 2 current iterations? I mean each team have a different iteration as current?

Thanks,

Ademar

Answer (score 1):

Well u can only have one current iteration for each project, however u can assign a iteration to each team by the TFS project administrator console u can choose "Set as team's backlog iteration". By this choice u give the selected team access to that iteration and all wich are hirachigly beneath it. This works for area's aswell.

Hope this will help you

For explaination see this blog:

[Blog Rene van osnabrugge](http://roadtoalm.com/2013/04/07/tfs-as-perfect-tool-for-scrum-part-2-product-backlog-grooming/)

Comment: Thanks Erick. I have dont that but unfortunately it still does not show right iteration per team. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Actually just for future reference, you CAN have more than one current iteration per project based on default iteration of teams.
http://blogs.ripple-rock.com/colinbird/2012/11/19/MultipleTeamsWithMicrosoftTeamFoundationServer2012VisualStudioScrumV2xUpdated1452013.aspx